# Pandas: Update values in one column based on the values from another pandas table

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine we have the following 2 pandas tables:

```
employee_id  country 
1            Sweden
2            Denmark
....
45           Germany
```

In another table I have the employee_id and want to create a new column where the country for the employee_ID is matched from the other table. Note that in this table the same employee_id can occur throughout multiple rows.

```
employee_id year salary 
1           2017  45000
2           2017  50000
1           2018  46000
....
```

How do I create the extra column on the last table using the information from the first table?

I was trying a code like:

```
df.loc[df.isin(df1.employee_id), 'country'] =  df1.loc[df1.employee_id.isin(df.id), 'country']
```

However that did not work.

Comment: Check out `map`

Comment: Isnt this simple `merge`? @coldspeed

Comment: @Erfan There are multiple ways of solving this, and `merge` would be one of them, yes. I would recommend `map` in this instance, however, because only one column needs merging. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), specifically the section on "Merging only a single column from one of the DataFrames".

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. @coldspeed